# Timer Countdown using dictionary to retrieve key value // "cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type String"

Tags: ios13, swift5, ios13.4

I'm trying to set up an egg timer, and display a countdown when the button is pressed. If "Soft" is pressed, the countdown begins at 300 seconds and so on.

However, this message keeps coming up "cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type String". What should I do?

[image: Egg Timer code]

and here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let eggTimer = ["Soft" : 300, "Medium" : 420, " Hard" : 720]
    var secondsRemaining = 60

    @IBAction func hardnessPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let hardness = [sender.currentTitle!]

        secondsRemaining = eggTimer[hardness]!
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if secondsRemaining > 0 {
            print(" \(secondsRemaining) second")
            secondsRemaining -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
let hardness = [sender.currentTitle!]
```

is wrong, you are mixing up Objective-C method call syntax `[object method...]` with property syntax `object.property`.

What Swift sees is an expression `sender.currentTitle!`, which accesses an Objective-C property, inside an array literal `[ ... ]`, and so creates an *array of 1 element* – `hardness` has type `[String]`, array of `String`, and not `String` as you expected.

Remove the `[` & `]`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Error screenshot 1 -

[image]

Fix screenshot 2

just adding **@objc** line number 21.

[image]